# How to populate URL with react-router based on search using UseParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use React-Router to make a sharable link for my web app. In the search bar the user types in a brand, and I want to use useParams to display the searched brand in the URL.

How would I approach this?

BrandTable.js is the component with the searchHandler function
TextInput.js is the component with the search bar.

SO far I can change the URl based on the brand I search, but if I open that URL in different window, the searched result is not there.

heres the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-banach-8jknp

```js
import { useHistory , useLocation, useParams} from "react-router";

const BrandTable = () -> {


const searchHandler = (searchString) =>
{

  
  let newFilters = {...filters} 
  newFilters.search = searchString
  setFilters(newFilters) 
  
  const params = new URLSearchParams()
  if (searchString) {
    params.append("brand", searchString)
  } 
  history.push({search: params.toString()})



return(
     <TextInput searchHandler={searchHandler} filters={filters}  />
     )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function TextInput(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    console.log(props.filters)

    return (
      <>
    <form   action="/" method="get" className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
   
      <TextField style={{width:"600px"}} onChange={(e)=>props.searchHandler(e.target.value)} value={props.filters.search}  id="outlined-basic" label={props.filters.search==''?'Search brand':''} variant="outlined" />

       
    </form>

    </>

  );
}

export default TextInput
```

[image]

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/using-url-parameters-and-query-strings-with-react-router-fffdcea7a8e9

Comment: It's very time consuming if you handle URL stuff by yourself. So that use a package for that. Highly recommended one is  https://reactrouter.com/web/api

Comment: Thats what im actually trying to use, But im having trouble understanding useParams to return the URL with the searched results